# CheckBoxList Horizontal

Tags: asp.net

Hy 
is it possible to do with checkboxlist this form :

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it to look exactly as the image you have included then you will have to create your own Custom `CheckboxList` and override the `Render` method

Answer (score 11):

Just set the RepeatDirection.

```
RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
```

Comment: please the picture below

Comment: can i have the text "Mon" above the square

Comment: You can achieve this easily by using datalist.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve your desire of having the label text above the checkbox, you'll need to use a little CSS. The below may not work 100% as I'm free writing this now, but should get the ball rolling for you.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" />
```

CSS

```
#CheckBoxList1 label{position: relative; top: -10px; left: -5px;}
```

Basically, target the label, which is the text that is displayed, and move it from where it's originally displayed.

Another approach would be to make the labels positioned absolute. Something like this would work....

```
#CheckBoxList1 td{position: relative;}
#CheckBoxList1 label{position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 5px;}
#CheckBoxList1 input{position: absolute: top: 10px: left: 0px;}
```

Again, might not be perfect, especially the pixel numbers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's not complicate :

try this

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:CheckBoxList id="cb1" runat="server"
**RepeatDirection="Horizontal"**>

Some content

</asp:CheckBoxList>
</form>
```

and look this [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_prop_webcontrol_checkboxlist_repeatdirection) .

Comment: follwing your demo , can  i have the text "item1" above the square